# iOS 8 Continuity Not Working

Tags: ios

I recently updated to iOS 8 (I am a developer, so it was completely legal) and I can't seem to get the continuity feature for picking up an email where you left off on my iPod touch 5th generation or iPad with Retina Display (iPad 3). Is there a special setting I have to set on my Mac? All 3 devices are on the same Apple ID.

Thanks!

**Edit:** I got a new MacBook Pro 2014 and it's still not working on either that with my iPod touch 5th generation or iPad 3. BlueTooth is on for all of them. If it's relevant, iBeacon works on the mobile devices, though.

**Edit #2:** It randomly started working. Sorry, I don't know how I fixed it.  If you're having the same problem, just make sure BlueTooth is on on both of your devices, handoff is not disabled, and that your Mac is supported.

Comment: Continuity is one of the elements that is not yet available in the betas. Wait for an update from Apple. Also, try not to post about the beta because your probably breaking your NDA.

Comment: @BritishColour - My friend's device runs it just fine. Thanks, though. If you have a source, for your info, that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken, but I think this is actually a bug, look at the release note for OSX10.10, I can't quote here, NDAs and all :)

Comment: Did you figure it out? Same setup and problem @BritishColour

Comment: You need Bluetooth turned on on both devices

Comment: Wait for the public release of Yosemite.